# android - data stored in onPause, onStop or onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, save, state

I have a confusion regarding what should go in `onPause`,`onStop` and `onSaveInstanceState`. For example, the Android docs say that 
For `onPause` -

> Commit unsaved changes, but only if users expect such changes to be permanently saved when they leave (such as a draft email).

For `onStop`-

> you should use onStop() to perform larger, more CPU intensive shut-down operations, such as writing information to a database.

For `onSaveInstanceState`

> your activity might have more state information that you'd like to restore, such as member variables that track the user's progress in the activity.

Isn't it true that these three things basically point to storing information like of a form, or an email ? Then in which method should it be saved ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everything that you want to be persistent must be stored in `onPause()` because some Android versions consider your app to be killable after `onPause()` returned.

The somewhat unclear distinction is being made because `onPause()` occurs relatively often, and also under many circumstances where you probably wouldn't save the state for an `onResume()` of the same Activity. Hence, everyone wants you to think twice before you perform expensive operations in `onPause()`.

Your question regarding storing form data, well, you could make that persistent right when an input field loses focus, if it's really totally intended that the user sees the same form data even after he stopped the app and started it again.

Comment: `onStop()` is guaranteed to be called since Honeycomb (3.0), which accounts for 96.8% of Android devices as of January 2016. So I prefer using `onStop()` over `onPause()` for saving data now.

Comment: @VickyChijwani From a software engineering standpoint, _preferring_ `onStop()` over `onPause()` is not acceptable, unless you _require_ Android 3.0 explicitly in your app's metadata (which you don't mention).

Comment: Right, I do make my apps for Android 3.0 and later, should've mentioned that. The other (debatable) reason I prefer `onStop()` is because of this line in the [`onPause()` docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause%28%29): "When activity B is launched in front of activity A, ... B will not be created until A's `onPause()` returns, so be sure to not do anything lengthy here." Of course, the lifecycle docs as a whole are still pretty confusing so this is not conclusive.

Comment: @VickyChijwani There are quite a few things which one wants to do in `onPause()` and which can't be done in `onStop()`. Unless your app doesn't do any of these things, of course. But there's a good chance that an app which don't do anything in `onPause()` isn't playing nice. After all, `onPause()` is called when the app stops interacting with the user, only to be resumed later.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone coming here in or after 2016, note that @Class Stacker's answer is quite out-dated at this point. Specifically, **`onStop()` is guaranteed to be called** since Android 3.0 (Honeycomb), which accounts for [**96.8% of Android devices**](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) as of January 2016.

See the lifecycle documentation here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle (Ctrl+F for "not in the killable state")

**UPDATE**: as rightly pointed out in the comments, this of course means that your app must be limited exclusively to Android 3.0 and above.

Comment: Just to make this clear again (also stated above), the percentage itself is not a sufficient point. An app which does not address persistency in `onPause()` must be strictly limited to Android 3 and above.